# How to replace this @synchronized(self) code with something more efficient?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have this getter/setter pair for a atomic retain property:

```
- (FileManager*)fileManager {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (fileManager) {
            return fileManager;
        }

        FileManager *fm = [[FileManager alloc] init];
        self.fileManager = fm;
        [fm release];

        return fileManager;
    }
}
- (void)setFileManager:(FileManager *)newFileManager {
    @synchronized(self) {
        [fileManager release];
        fileManager = [newFileManager retain];
    }
}
```

Now someone said @synchronized(self) is very slow and NSLock is a lot faster. He also said that the magic @synthesize implementation typically used doesn't use @synchronize(self) but something a lot more efficient instead.

So how does this Voodoo magic has to look like, in this case?

Comment: how to use `NSLock`: http://alienryderflex.com/NSLock.html  .

Comment: Have you profiled your app with Instruments to make sure that this is actually slowing down your application appreciably?

Comment: curious - did you go with the pthread_mutex?  what were your findings?

Answer (score 3):

This article here concluded that pthread_mutex was the fastest.  It has code samples as well.

http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSLockVsSynchronized

But, the most important thing is for you to measure in your own app.

Also, measure the simplest approach: @synthesize of the (atomic, retain) property.  That of course would have the least code and you wouldn't have to maintain code when they optimize it in the compiler - you would get their optimizations for free.

Comment: Nice! But I cannot use @synthesize when overwriting a setter or getter for any reason. Here I need to do lazy initialization.

Comment: BTW, I couldn't resist viewing your profile with a name like dontWatchMyProfile :) nice.

Comment: I thought the name was pretty clear. Now you've wasted some time! Sorry for that ;-)